# Querying svc log file with logParser

Tags: enterprise-library, trace, logparser, svc

I have generated a xml trace for my program using the Enterprise Library TraceManager. It works great. Using the Microsoft Service Trace Viewer, I can see a separate trace per call.

I would love to query the file so I found Microsoft Logparser and was hopeful I could use that. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out the expected input format. Input of XML returns a error of more than one root node found for the document. None of the other format parse the correct number of line.

Has anyone had any success querying a SVCLog File

```
TraceManager traceManager
traceManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<TraceManager>();
TraceLogEntry traceEntry = new TraceLogEntry();  

 using (this.traceManager.StartTrace("Tracing")){                
    traceEntry.Title = "Message";
    traceEntry.Priority = Priority;
    this.traceManager.LogWriter.Write(traceEntry);
 }
```

The Tracing Category is hooked up to a XML trace listener:

```
< loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
 < listeners>
   < add name="XML Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.XmlTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.XmlTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    fileName="c:\A2ISOtrace.svclog" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId" />
< /listeners>
< categorySources>    
 < add switchValue="All" name="Tracing">
    < listeners>
      < add name="XML Trace Listener" />
    < /listeners>
  < /add>
< /categorySources>
```

Log produces a number of rows like:

```
  < E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System <EventID>1</EventID><Type>3</Type>. . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your SVCLog file is missing a root element you could embed it into a basic Xml document.

**The Xml document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Root SYSTEM "Test.dtd">
<Root>
    &svclog;
</Root>
```

**The DTD document**

```
<!ENTITY svclog SYSTEM "SVCLog.xml">
```

where you declare the `ENTITY` *svclog* importing your SVCLog file.

Now you should be able to parse the Xml input.